# Sugar ORM throws NoSuchTable exception on lollipop

Tags: android, sqlite, sugarorm

I am developing an Android app. I followed instructions on Sugar ORM website for creating a database table. I do everything the same, I've double checked it.

The thing is, when the app is running on Android 5.0 or higher, when a query is executed, it throws a SQLiteException and says no such table.
Same code executes fine on KitKat devices and leads to right result, without any exception.

Does Sugar ORM support Andriod 5.0?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a sample model? Also, what version of Sugar ORM are you using?

Comment: I have the same problem... is ur problem solved?

Comment: @SatZ I think I resolved it by debugging the Sugar library and going through code line by line. Add some break points in the library initialization and table creation classes. This way you'll know if tables are created, and if they're not, what is the problem. BTW, Sugar does not work with the new Instant Run feature in Android Studio 2.0.

Comment: @mehrmoudi I resolved it. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/37944868/4340022 It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using SugarORM 1.3 you need to retain the default constructor NO PARAMETERS should be passed into the constructor ,
in addition of a problem i ran into several times that is at some point during development when you create a new class extending the SugarRecord it does not get created until either you increment the version of the database in the manifest file or clear the cache of the application.

SugarORM is really easy to use and fast to develop with as long as you're not running into troubles , but the moment you need support it really really lacks documentation

Comment: I'm getting crash in KitKat and in rest it is working fine. -_-

Comment: did you try migrating the database by incrementing the database version in the manifest ?

Comment: I solved it by using the latest version 1.5. Earlier it was 1.3