# SugarORM : While instrumentation testing, No such table Exception

Tags: android, testing, sugarorm

This is my `ApplicationTest.java`

```
package com.example.testing;

import android.app.Application;
import android.test.ApplicationTestCase;

import com.example.agent.database.MyGroupsTable;
import com.orm.SugarContext;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * <a href="http://d.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html">Testing Fundamentals</a>
 */
public class ApplicationTest extends ApplicationTestCase<Application> {
    static final String DB_NAME = "database.db";

    public ApplicationTest() {
        super(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        boolean deleted = mContext.deleteDatabase(DB_NAME);
        SugarContext.init(mContext);
    }

    /**
     * :Check: tables created or not
     */
    public void testDatabase() {
        int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            MyGroupsTable table = new MyGroupsTable();
            long i = table.save();
            assertTrue("Failed check table", i >= 0);
        } else {
            MyGroupsTable i = MyGroupsTable.findById(MyGroupsTable.class, (long) 0);
            long j = MyGroupsTable.save(new MyGroupsTable("1", "testing", "description", "avatar"));
            assertTrue("Failed to create table", j < 0);
            List<MyGroupsTable> my = MyGroupsTable.find(MyGroupsTable.class, " GROUPID = ?", "1");
            if (my.size() > 0) {
                assertTrue(true);
            } else {
                assertTrue(false);
            }

            assertTrue("Failed to get results from MyGroupsTable", my.get(0).getGroup_id().equals("1"));
        }
    }

}
```

I am using SugarORM. Which is working fine when running the app as debug or release but when i tries to execute Instrumentation test it blows up with Exception

This is the Stack Trace 
    Testing started at 4:36 PM ...

```
06/16 16:36:44: Launching ApplicationTest
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/sandeeprana/StudioProjects/iliad_agent/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.loktra.iliadagent
$ adb push /Users/sandeeprana/StudioProjects/iliad_agent/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug-androidTest-unaligned.apk /data/local/tmp/com.loktra.iliadagent.test
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.loktra.iliadagent.test"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.loktra.iliadagent.test
Success


Running tests

$ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class com.example.agent.ApplicationTest com.example.agent.test/com.android.test.runner.MultiDexTestRunner
Client not ready yet..Test running started

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: MY_GROUPS_TABLE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT OR REPLACE  INTO MY_GROUPS_TABLE(ID,GROUPDESCRIPTION,GROUPNAME,GROUPID,GROUPAVATAR) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:686)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1573)
at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:266)
at com.orm.SugarRecord.save(SugarRecord.java:360)
at com.loktra.iliadagent.ApplicationTest.testDatabase(ApplicationTest.java:40)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1700)
```

Tests ran to completion.

The code is working fine on pre-Lollipop and post Lollipop devices while running as debug/release.
But i try to execute Instrumentation Testing.
It throws no such Table Exception.

Answer (score 0):

From ref : https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/613#issuecomment-223300514

Create a class:

```
public class App extends SugarApp {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SugarContext.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTerminate() {
        SugarContext.terminate();
        super.onTerminate();
    }
}
```

Then specify it in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    ...
    android:name=".App">
    ...
</application>
```

Uninstall app, disable instarun, Then run again.It worked for me.